# What data of a deployment object may change during its lifetime?

Tags: azure-deployment, azure-rest-api

I want to cache a deployment object, querying it directly after its creation via it's URL, like

```
GET /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/...
```

If we exclude resource group change, what are the parameters that could change during its lifetime ? What parameters could change of the returned object later on ?

In particular:

- Can any of the deployment **outputs** change ?
- Can any of the **outputResources** change ?

Answer (score 1):

The deployment resource is really just a "log" of the activity that happened when the deployment was created by the template.

The URI of the deployment will never change but everything else about it can change - as it can be overwritten by a subsequent deployment of the same name.  In that subsequent deployment all the properties (except the URI) can change - inputs, outputs, resources, mode, etc.

The deployment may also be deleted automatically if the number of deployments in that scope (in this case the resourceGroup) exceeds the max allowed (800).  In this case deployments are deleted in FIFO order (i.e. starting with the oldest).

That help?

Comment: Thanks. To refine my question: if we exclude deployment updates (or subsequent deployment with the same name) and automatic deletions, what can change in a deployment object ?

Comment: Once the deployment has reached a terminal state, nothing.